# overwrite conf file android wpa_supplicant

Tags: android, bash, wpa-supplicant

Using a rooted phone I am trying to overwrite the wpa_supplicant file. I want to remove all the entries in here without going via the GUI (I underdtsand this was impossible in earlier versions of android). I can access the file /data/misc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf and when I cat it out I can see all the entries.

an rm removes the file, but after a couple of minutes it appears back unchanged with the original values, I have also tried writing blank over it via >.

is this file (or all config files) stored somewhere else and overwriting my values?

Comment: I beleive it could be network manager but lsof returns far too much output to find anything suitable